# How many people kiss Usagi in the Sailor Moon anime and manga respectively?

Tags: sailor-moon

My wife is a big fan of Sailor Moon, a series I know little about.

How many people kiss Usagi in the manga and anime respectively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the **manga**, Usagi/Sailor Moon/Princess Serenity/Neo Queen Serenity is kissed by:

1. Prince Endymion kissed Princess Serenity (Moon Kingdom, consensual)
2. Chiba Mamoru/Tuxedo Kamen kissed Usagi/Sailor Moon (present day, in every story arc, non-consensual and consensual)
3. Prince Demande kissed Usagi (*Black Moon* arc, non-consensual)
4. Neo Queen Serenity kissed King Endymion (*Black Moon* arc, the King was asleep so technically non-consensual)
5. Sailor Uranus kissed Sailor Moon (*Mugen* [*Infinty*] arc, done by Uranus before Sailor Moon could react, so technically non-consensual, but Sailor Moon did not seem to mind). [Tenou Haruka also almost kissed Usagi](https://gallery.missdream.org/albums/raws/japanese/smoon_kan/volume%2005/203.jpg) (consensual) but they were interrupted by Mamoru. Usagi also imagined herself being kissed by surprise by Haruka (her face expression in her mind's eye is one of shock, so she was imagining a non-consensual kiss, but since she is the one who thought it up, it could be that she subconsciously wouldn't mind if it happened).
6. Seiya Kou (*Stars* arc, done by Seiya before Usagi could react, so technically non-consensual, but Usagi did not seem to mind)

In the **classic 90s anime**:

1. Prince Endymion kissed Princess Serenity (Moon Kingdom, consensual)
2. Chiba Mamoru/Tuxedo Kamen kissed Usagi/Sailor Moon (present day, in every season, non-consensual and consensual)
3. Prince Demande kissed Usagi (*R* season, non-consensual)
4. Sailor Chibi-Moon kissed Sailor Moon (*SuperS* season, during transformation sequence, non-romantic on the cheek, consensual)
5. Seiya Kou kissed Usagi (*SailorStars* season, on the cheek, Usagi pulled back so technically non-consensual, but Usagi seemed more sad to have to reject him than disturbed by his farewell kiss)

In ***Sailor Moon Crystal***:

1. Prince Endymion kissed Princess Serenity (Moon Kingdom, consensual)
2. Chiba Mamoru/Tuxedo Kamen kissed Usagi/Sailor Moon (present day, non-consensual and consensual)
3. Prince Demande kissed Usagi (non-consensual)
4. Neo Queen Serenity kissed King Endymion (the King was asleep so technically non-consensual)
5. Sailor Uranus kissed Sailor Moon (*Mugen* [*Infinty*] season, done by Uranus before Sailor Moon could react, so technically non-consensual, but Sailor Moon did not seem to mind). Usagi also imagined herself being kissed by Haruka.

A few examples:

Non-Consensual:

(Tuxedo Kamen kisses drunk sleeping Sailor Moon)[image]

[image]

[image: Seiya and Usagi kiss]

Consensual:
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Haruka kisses Usagi without warning (both while in Sailor Guardian form) in ep. 3 of the new SMC season.

Comment: @Maroon, thanks, your comment made me realize I'd written "Usagi" instead of "Sailor Moon" in the manga section. I fixed that, and added mention of when, in the manga, Usagi imagined getting kissed without warning by Haruka. (On another note, despite _Crystal_ purporting to rather religiously follow the manga, where almost all of Uranus/Haruka's romantic scenes were with Sailor Moon/Usagi rather than with Neptune/Michiru, the 3rd season ED seems to be another case of _Crystal_ deviating, like it did by pairing guardians with Shitenou. It could try to be more up-front about this tendency...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I would hesitate to replace "Selenity" with "Serenity" - a brief bit of googling suggests that both are viable transliterations. (Pun on "Selene" and all.)

Comment: @senshin I would agree more (a) if one weren't a relatively common word where the other is at best an obscure phrase, and (b) more to the point, if there weren't a canonical English transliteration with literally two decades of precedent behind it.

Comment: There is no official consensus on whether she's Serenity or Selenity; the official Japanese merchandise used both spellings:  trading cards [1](http://www.genvid.com/diesgaudii/articles/sere/nqs.jpg), [2](http://www.genvid.com/diesgaudii/articles/sere/ps-smw.jpg) & [3](http://www.genvid.com/diesgaudii/articles/sere/selenity.jpg), [figure](http://www.genvid.com/diesgaudii/articles/sere/princessserenity.jpg), [VHS](http://www.genvid.com/diesgaudii/articles/sere/video-serenity.jpg). Ian Andreas Miller’s in-depth analysis of the two options is [here](http://www.genvid.com/diesgaudii/articles/sere)